# Radio buttons not getting selected in window.print()

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to print the form data.All the data inside text box are coming in the preview of the print except radio buttons and checkboxes. Only the labels are displaying for radio buttons and checkboxes.

When I view in the page radio button is getting selected. But if I click print button in the preview and also after printing radio button values are not selected only labels are present like Male Female. Can anyone tell how I can get the value of radio button selected into print preview?

```js
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
  printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
  var modThis = document.querySelector("#printThis");
  window.print();
}

function printElement(elem) {
  var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
  var $printThis = document.getElementById("printThis");
  $printThis.innerHTML = "";
  $printThis.appendChild(domClone);
}
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printThis,
  #printThis * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #printThis {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="printThis">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btnPrint">Print</button>
  </div>
  <div class="margin-top-8">
    <label class="control control--radio">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" ng-model="formData.gender">
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" ng-model="formData.gender">
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works in Chrome for me.

Comment: Yeah here it is working.But not in my application.There after clicking specific user i am displaying all the details.In that form details gender field is also present.Radio button will be selected in that page.But if i click print its not displaying in preview

Comment: The snippet does not show the issue. Perhaps you have some other scripting that deselects it? Also have a read of this: https://twitter.com/mspowahs/status/955851780411109376

Comment: If you don't see them in Print Preview, some styles that only apply for "print" media are interfering.

Comment: I have updated my question.I have added css.Can you check?

Comment: Also do you have ng-model or ng-\nmodel in the HTML?

Comment: ng-model i am using

Answer (score 0):

Just add this on your style and your problem will be solved:

```
@media print {
  .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #00695C inset !important;
  }
}
```

in your code :

```js
document.getElementById("btnPrint").onclick = function() {
  printElement(document.getElementById("printThis"));
  var modThis = document.querySelector("#printThis");
  window.print();
}

function printElement(elem) {
  var domClone = elem.cloneNode(true);
  var $printThis = document.getElementById("printThis");
  $printThis.innerHTML = "";
  $printThis.appendChild(domClone);
}
```

```css
@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #printThis,
  #printThis * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #printThis {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .mat-radio-inner-circle {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px #00695C inset !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="printThis">
  <div class="col-md-2">
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="btnPrint">Print</button>
  </div>
  <div class="margin-top-8">
    <label class="control control--radio">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" ng-model="formData.gender">
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
    <label class="control control--radio">Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" ng-model="formData.gender">
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding bellow CSS in the global CSS file worked for me

```css
  @media print {

    html,
    body {
      overflow-x: unset !important;
    }

    .mat-radio-button.mat-accent .mat-radio-inner-circle {
      background-color: #00ABFE !important;
    }
  }
```

Also make sure below browser settings also are set.
The recommended solution for this issue is to have the end user adjust their Print Settings:

- For Chrome in the Print Preview screen, click More Settings. Ensure "Background graphics" is checked.
- For Internet Explorer from the Print Preview screen, click Page Setup. Ensure "Print Background Colors and Images" is checked.
- For FireFox from the Print Preview screen, click Page Setup. Ensure "Print Background (colors and images)" is checked.